# React Native - Module Lifecycle - Dispose resources on "Reload"

Tags: android, bluetooth, react-native

I am using a react native module (https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial) for Bluetooth communication with an Arduino.

Eveything works just fine. But when I press "Reload" or the application reloads due to Live Reload being enabled, the `onDestroy` method of the module is not called. Because of that, the sockets (and streams) are no correctly disposed.

When the reload is finished, I can no longer open a bluetooth socket. It requires me to disable and enable bluetooth, or to restart the application.

Is there ant callback or method I could implement that would correctly dispose these sockets when I reload my application?

Comment: Ever solve this?

Comment: Wow... I have the very same problem! Did anyone ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok after spending time in react-native code I found the answer to this:

**On iOS:**

You'll have to implement a method called `invalidate` in your `RCTBridgeModule` implementation:

That will run whenever the context is destroyed (the app is reloaded) and it will look like this:

```
- (void)invalidate
{
    // disconnect bluetooth here
}
```

Here's [an example](https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-mqtt/blob/master/ios/RCTMqtt.m#L118:L121) of how I did it on iOS.

**On Android:**

you'll have to implement the `onCatalystInstanceDestroy` method inside your `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` and it will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCatalystInstanceDestroy() {
    // disconnect bluetooth here
}
```

Here's [an example](https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-mqtt/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/tuanpm/RCTMqtt/RCTMqttModule.java#L134:L137) of how I did it on Android.

Answer (score 2):

It seems we can use `@Override public void onCatalystInstanceDestroy() {}` without the need of implementing anything.
That method will be called before the current JS bundle is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

#### on iOS

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
       
    NSLog(@"whatever you want");
    
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // by the way, you do not need the following line because of ARC
    // [super dealloc];

    NSLog(@"whatever you want");
}
```

I prefer use dealloc rather than invalidate
because react-native api may change in the future...

#### on android

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class YourModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {

    ...

    YourModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        Log.d("YourModuleLog", "whatever you want");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {}

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {}

    @Override
    public void onHostDestroy() {
        Log.d("YourModuleLog", "not trigger after fast reload");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCatalystInstanceDestroy() {
        Log.d("YourModuleLog", "whatever you want");
    }
}
```

only override `onCatalystInstanceDestroy` does not work for me
unless I also add `LifecycleEventListener`.